# Replacing 1,2,3 to Regular, Staff, Supporter

Tags: php, session

So I have some PHP code written down. How do I get the membership do display these:

```
0 is Regular
1 is Staff
2 is Supporter
```

Right now, all the membership displays are 0,1,2,

Here is the code:

```
<p>Membership: <?php echo user_fetch($_SESSION['id'], 'membership', 1); ?></p>
```

Comment: Please don't use images of code in a question - paste the code instead (even if it is a single line).

Comment: Where does the value 0, 1 or 2 come from? is that the output from the `user_fetch` function?

Comment: It's just what's in the Database.

Comment: Where's the code for that `user_fetch` function? What does it currently do? Why not handle the replacement in that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming the output of the `user_fetch` function below is 0, 1, or 2:

```
user_fetch($_SESSION['id'], 'membership', 1)
```

You could do something like this to get a textual output using a `switch` statement to choose the correct membership type:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
$membershipType = 'Unknown';
switch (user_fetch($_SESSION['id'], 'membership', 1)) {
    case 0:
        $membershipType = 'Regular';
        break;
    case 1:
        $membershipType = 'Staff';
        break;
    case 2:
        $membershipType = 'Supporter';
        break;
}
?>
<p>Membership: <?php echo $membershipType; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of the various types and just output the corresponding one, you can add `?? 'Unknown'` (for PHP 7+) or something to display if no match is found

```
$userTypes = ['Regular', 'Staff', 'Supporter'];
?>
<p>Membership: <?php echo $userTypes[user_fetch($_SESSION['id'], 'membership', 1)] 
                                       ?? 'Unknown' ?></p>
```

Comment: Note: `??` is PHP 7+ exclusive ternary.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I've added this to the answer - thanks.  Would be nice to think that we can *assume* PHP 7+, but wonder how many years that will take :-/

Comment: Welcome Nigel. It will be a matter of time when all servers will be on PHP 7, which in many instances is a good thing, and in others not so good, given some deprecated functions.